# Is it possible to Get 'style' property values from React Native Element AFTER rendering using useRef?

Tags: react-native, react-typescript, use-ref, react-forwardref

I'm trying to dynamically apply `margin` & `padding` to a `View`, based on a `ref`'d `TextInput`'s `borderRadius`. I am new to React coming from Xamarin where this type of thing is common.

I'm not sure if I have the correct approach, but I have seen some examples of people deriving `style` values from `useRef`.

Here is my custom `LabelInput` component:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Animated,
  StyleSheet,
  ViewProps,
} from 'react-native';

import {Colors} from '../../../resources/colors';
import Text from './Text';
import TextInput from './TextInput';
import {TextInputProps} from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInput';
import {isNullOrWhiteSpace} from '../../../utils/stringMethods';
import {TextProps} from 'react-native/Libraries/Text/Text';

interface LabeledInputProps {
  label: string;
  error: string;
  onChangeText: (text: string) => void;
  placeholder?: string;
  inputValue: string;
  mask?: (text: string) => string;
  validator?: (text: string) => string;
  onValidate?: (value: string) => void;
  viewProps?: ViewProps;
  textProps?: TextProps;
  errorTextProps?: TextProps;
  inputProps?: TextInputProps;
}

export default function LabeledInput(props: LabeledInputProps) {
  const inputRef = React.useRef<any>(null);
  const [dynamicStyle, setDynamicStyle] = useState(StyleSheet.create({
    dynamicContainer:{
        marginHorizonal: 0,
        paddingHorizonal: 0,
    }
  }));

  const changeTextHandler = (inputText: string) => {
    const displayText = props?.mask ? props.mask(inputText) : inputText;
    props.onChangeText(displayText);

    // ultimately not the exact behavior I'm after, but this is a simple example.
    var test = inputRef.current.props.style; 
    // props.style always returns undefined, 
    // there doesn't appear to be a 'props' property on the 'current' object when debugging.
    setDynamicStyle(StyleSheet.create({
        dynamicContainer:{
            marginHorizonal: test.borderRadius, // I want the padding/margin of this element to be
            paddingHorizonal: test.borderRadius,// dynamically set based on the inputRef's borderRadius
        }
      }))
  };

  return (
    <View
      {...props.viewProps}
      style={[
        props.viewProps?.style,
        localStyles.container,
      ]}>
      <TextInput
        ref={inputRef}
        {...props.inputProps}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        style={localStyles.input}
        onChangeText={changeTextHandler}
        value={props.inputValue}
      />
      <Animated.View
        pointerEvents={'none'}>
        <Text
          {...props.textProps}
          style={[props.textProps?.style, animatedStyles.label]}>
          {props.label}
        </Text>
      </Animated.View>
      {/* {stuff} */}
    </View>
  );
}

const localStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flex: 1,
  },
  label: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 8,
  },
  input: {
    padding: 8,
  },
  error: {
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    fontSize: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    color: Colors.danger,
    marginTop: 4,
  },
});

const animatedStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  label: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'normal',
  },
});
```

Here is my custom `LabelInput` component with `forwardRef()` implemented:

```js
import React, {ForwardedRef, forwardRef} from 'react';
import {TextInput as NativeTextInput, TextInputProps} from 'react-native';
import {useGlobalStyles} from '../../../resources/styles';

const TextInput = (
  props: TextInputProps,
  ref: ForwardedRef<NativeTextInput>,
) => {
  const styles = useGlobalStyles();
  return (
    <NativeTextInput
      {...props}
      ref={ref}
      style={[styles.textInput, props.style]}
      placeholderTextColor={styles.textInput.borderColor}
      onChangeText={(text: string) => {
        if (props.onChangeText) {
          props.onChangeText(text);
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default forwardRef(TextInput);
```

I've tried referencing `inputRef` from different hooks, like `useCallback` & `useEffect`.

`var test = inputRef.current.props.style;` always returns undefined. And there doesn't appear to be a 'props' property on the 'current' object when debugging.

Comment: You can access input styles like this `inputRef.current.style`.

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique I tried this and it is still undefined, at least from inside of the `changeTextHandler()` you see in the example above. Something is off.

Comment: In `LabeledInput` component where you pass inputProps `{...props.inputProps}`. Turn this off may be ref is override by `props.inputProps`. If it doesn't solve this issue, please create a code sandbox.

Comment: Where do you recommend I make a 'code sandbox'? That didn't work either it seems `inputRef.current` should be type of `MutableRefObject`, but it returns this: `ReactNativeFiberHostComponent`

Comment: Use this template [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/q4qymyp2l6)

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique https://8djq65.csb.app/ thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

The link you mentioned contains two files with `inputRef`. Since `inputRef` is in parent component and use `ref` prop to pass inputRef, this will not work. `ref` is not available as prop. If you still want to use ref as prop, then use forward ref in child component as access the ref as second argument or you can use any other prop name to pass ref i.e. `innerRef`. You can read more in react documentation. [Forward Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

According to the code you attach in code sandbox, i think you are trying to access input styles in two components: `App` and `LabeledInput`. You should use one ref in main component and use it in LabelInput component. If you still want to have separate refs then you can ref callback function and attach the node with both refs.

```
const attachRef = (node: NativeTextInput) => {
    inputRef.current = node;
    ref.current = node;
};

return <TextInput ref={attachRef} />;
```

The correct type for inputRef.current is `TextInputProps`.

```
const inputRef = useRef() as MutableRefObject<TextInputProps>;
```

I have updated the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-meadow-9o4fwx?file=/src/LabeledInput.tsx). I was able to access input field styles in both components. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: The behavior in React Native seems to be different when working with Mobile devices, I tried your [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-meadow-9o4fwx?file=/src/LabeledInput.tsx), where `const attachRef = (node: NativeTextInput)` does in fact return an HTML `<input/>`, with Android I am still getting a `ReactNativeFiberHostComponent` with no `props` or `style`.